# How can I show that these sets are convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

We have

\begin{align}
&A = \big\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m: x_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i = 1 \big\}\\
        &B = \big\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n: y_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i = 1 \big\}.
\end{align}

How can we show that they are convex?

Comment: Just apply the definition of convex set...

Comment: @Guillerminho77 care to elaborate?

Comment: The common topos of hemi hyper planes?

Comment: @dmtri do you mean semi hyper planes?

Comment: Why do you ask the same thing for A,  B?  Are not they the same thing?

Comment: Yes,  bad language sorry.

Comment: @dmtri sorry mate that's all I have been given I have been asking this for 3 months now on stackexchange if you have a complete answer please write it so I can put this to rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137327/discussion-between-algevristis-and-dmtri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that a set $C$ is convex if
$$\forall x,y\in C,\;,\forall \lambda\in[0,1]\;, \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in C$$
Now take $x,y\in A$, and lets take $\lambda\in (0,1)$, the extreme cases $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1$ are trivial.
Lets call $z:=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$. Is $z$ in the set $A$?. By definiton of set $A$, $z\in A\iff \sum_{i=1}^{m}z_i=1$. But for every $i=1,\cdots,m$, $z_i=\lambda x_i+(1-\lambda)y_i$. So:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}z_i=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\lambda x_i+(1-\lambda)y_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{m}(1-\lambda)y_i=\lambda\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i+(1-\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^{m}y_i=\lambda+1-\lambda=1$$ So $z\in A\implies A$ is convex.

The reasoning for $B$ is exactly the same, because are the same set for different dimensions